# Напишите пож-та о Поэзии

Tags: литература, история, поэзия

Время возникновения
Виды или направления

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, определение слова "поэзия" (или "Поэзия"), тогда мы будем знать, о чём разговор...

Answer (score 3):

Поэзия как стихотворные произведения относится к литературному роду "лирика".

В древнегреческой литературе VII–VI вв. до н. э. обострившиеся противоречия между коллективом и личностью подтолкнули возникновение и развитие жанра лирики, которому свойственно прежде всего личное поэтическое самовыражение.

Термин «лирика» происходит от названия древнегреческого музыкального инструмента – лиры. Под её аккомпанемент и исполнялись произведения лирического жанра. Само понятие «лирика» было позже введено александрийскими учеными, которые основывали это наименование на формальных признаках – на характере аккомпанемента. В новое время термином «лирика» определяли содержание поэтического жанра, сложившегося в Древней Греции в VII–VI вв. до н. э. Поэтому лирическими сейчас называют стихотворения, передающие мысли и чувства автора, его настроения, его мгновенные душевные движения

Сейчас в поэзии различают  следующие жанры:  лирическая, публицистическая, юмористическая(ироническая), эпическая и смешение жанров – лиро-эпическая поэзия. Лирическая поэзия подразделяется на любовную, пейзажную, о животных, лирику дружбы,философскую, духовную. Публицистическая - на вольнолюбивую лирику, патриотическую, политические стихи.

http://philologos.narod.ru/classics/belinsky1.htm

http://rushist.com/index.php/greece-rome/1886-drevnegrecheskaya-lirika